# ItextSharp horizontal aligning issue with fixed Y cordinates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext, pdf-generation

I am using ItextSharp lib for writing pdf. I have to print the name of the student on a pdf certificate template. I am not able to center align the student name with fixed y co-ordinate.

```
 private byte[] CreatePDF2(UserCourseViewModel userCourse)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(Request.MapPath("/Templates/Certificate.pdf")), null);
        Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        Document doc = new Document(size);

        using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output);
            doc.Open();


            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

            cb.BeginText();
            try
            {
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
                cb.AddTemplate(page,0,0);
                cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(), 24);
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Student Name", (size.Width) / 2, 350, 0);
            }
            finally
            {
                cb.EndText();
            }


            doc.Close();


            return output.ToArray();
        }
```

The Y-Coordinate seems to be correct by the x coordinate is surely not at the center. I  am unable to figure out a way where irrespective of the student name it will always be horizontally centered on the certificate.
I am open to any other tool as my requirement is very simple I just need to open the pdf template and write the Student Name on the course certificate. (ITextSharp seems to be too complicated for this task)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, for aligning a paragraph.

```
    cb.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER);
```